# Создание игры на C#

Tags: c#

Будучи студентом первого курса, после ознакомления с событиями и основами работы с Windows Forms получил задание написать игру на C#. Возник следующий вопрос, можно ли написать простенькую 2d-стрелялку (вид сверху), работая только c Windows Forms? Если да, то было бы неплохо откопать какие-нибудь примерчики реализаций.

Comment: Можно. Пишите! И делайте это самостоятельно если хотите чему-нибудь научиться.

Comment: (1) Можно, легко. (2) Это достаточно много работы по отладке, хотя в сотню строк можно вполне уложиться. Пишите сами.

Comment: Понимаю что вам нужно на с#, но если надумаете для себя делать, то переходите на с++ и OpenGL. Советую канал на Ютюбе -  "MakingGamesWithBen", около 80 толковых уроков, шаг за шагом научат вас не только основам плюсов, но и 1D играм, 2D играм... движкам. 
Жаль автор уже не делает видео уроки... Устроился на работу в Guild Wars 2... Походу 3D уже не будет Q_Q

Answer (score 2):

Разумеется можно. Только примеры, скорее всего, придется искать в гугле и долго, т.к. нынешние игроделы ленивы до безобразия и предпочитают использовать готовые движки и фреймворки. Хотя с точки зрения бизнеса это наверное правильно, но порождает массу однотипных игр отличающихся только шкурками.

А теперь по делу:

1. Неважно какой графический движок вы будете использовать. Чистый DirectX или OpenGL, Unity или UE4, WinForms или WPF, разница только в том, сколько потребуется делать дополнительной работы по адаптации готового движка или дописыванию функционала к "чистой" платформе для реализации вашей задумки.
2. Сразу, еще на этапе обдумывания, разделите модель игры и ее визуализацию. чтобы не было мучительно больно добавлять новые фичи, тестировать и фиксить баги. Логика должна быть отдельно, графика - отдельно.
3. Если хотите написать игру - просто начните ее писать. Не ищите готовые решения и не бойтесь ошибок. Отрицательный результат лучше десятка положительных, т.к. после неудачи остаются опыт и знания.

Все выше описанное сугубо личное мнение.

Comment: Полностью согласен! Важно просто начать что то делать. А уже по ходу дела у Вас будут появляться вопросы по реализации той или иной функции, ответы на которые можно найти либо в интернете, либо у друзей или даже возможно преподаватель в вузе что-то подскажет.
Даже если если в первый раз игра получится так себе с точки зрения реализации в след. раз Вы сможете учесть все проблемные места прошлой реализации и сделать новую игру намного лучше.